# Using column alias in inner select in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

It seems that I can't alias a column and use it in the inner select in MySql.
How do I do the following in MySql for example?

```
SELECT NAME,ID AS M_ID FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MANAGERS WHERE MANAGERID = M_ID)
```

MySql would not recognize `M_ID` alias!

My table structure:

```
EMPLOYEES (ID,NAME) 
MANAGERS (MANAGERID,...)
```

Answer (score 5):

Either just use the original column name - this should work as long as the `MANAGERS` table does not have an `ID` column:

```
SELECT NAME, ID AS M_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM MANAGERS 
    WHERE MANAGERID = ID
)
```

Or better yet, use an alias for the tables:

```
SELECT e.NAME, e.ID AS M_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES AS e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM MANAGERS AS m
    WHERE m.MANAGERID = e.ID
)
```

Column aliases can only be used in the `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses. Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` code is executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

By the way - using a subselect for the given problem might not be the best solution. Even though in this simple case I'd assume that the MySQL query optimizer can find a simple way in the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?  Looks like it is to get all employees where there is a matching record in the manager table?

If that is the case couldn't you use

```
SELECT
  e.name
, e.id
FROM
  employees AS e
  inner join managers AS m ON (e.id = m.managerid)
```